# Net Core Async tasks

Tags: asynchronous, .net-core, async-await

I have a web API over net core 3.0 and my API is using a mail DLL where I do some operations.

Web API controller:

```
_mailService.SendEmail();
```

Mail DLL:

```
public void SendEmail()
{
     Console.Writeline("Registering at database");

     RegisterAtDatabase();  //Do some stuff at database

     SendMailToUser();   //Send mail to user. His operation takes about 1 minute

     Console.Writeline("End mail proccess");
}

private void SendMailToUser()
{
     Console.Writeline("Creating and sending mail");
     
    //Here some stuff to send the mail. It takes about 1 minute
     
    Console.Writeline("Mail sended");
}
```

I want to call _mailService.SendEmail() and not wait for the whole process. I want to write at the database and not wait for email sending process. So console output should be....

```
Registering at database
Creating and sending mail
End mail proccess
//After 1 minute
Mail sended
```

Is that possible using Task Async and await in some way?

I wanna return the control to the API while the email is sending.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is that possible using Task Async and await in some way?

No, [that's not what `async` is for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net#asynchronous-code-is-not-a-silver-bullet).

The proper solution is to write the work (e.g., "send this message to this email address") to a reliable queue (e.g., Azure Queue / Amazon SQS / etc), and then have a separate background process read and process that queue (e.g., ASP.NET Core background service / Azure Function / Amazon Lambda / etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use background Task queue for this kind of works and run them in the background.

full info at Microsoft Documents [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Is not possible to do with other approach?